# Return multiple columns in SQL consult

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I need to create a query to return multiple values ​that are in the same table and return it as a column of the result for example:

In this table the path value is different but it can have the same id_location.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Address,
    path
from
    `table_location` as A
inner JOIN table_images as B
on A.id = B.id_location

where A.des
```

This retun

```
test1, example, pathExample1
test1, example, pathExample2
test3, example, pathExample3
test3, example, pathExample4
```

how return path in columns?

Example:

```
test1, example, pathExample1, pathExample2
test3, example, pathExample3, pathExample4
```

how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Address,
    group_concat(path) as path
from
    `table_location` as A
inner JOIN table_images as B
on A.id = B.id_location
group by Name,Address
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use `group_concat()`:

```
select name, address, group_concat(path) as paths
from table_location l join
     table_images i
     on l.id = i.id_location
where A.des
group by name, address;
```

This puts the results into a single column.  If you want two columns, then you can use:

```
select name, address, min(path), nullif(max(path), min(path))
from table_location l join
     table_images i
     on l.id = i.id_location
where A.des
group by name, address;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question, as I understand it, is how to pivot the images of each location to different columns.

If you know in advance the maximum number of images per location, you can do conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select l.name, l.address,
    max(case when i.rn = 1 then i.path end) path1,
    max(case when i.rn = 2 then i.path end) path2,
    max(case when i.rn = 3 then i.path end) path3
from table_location l
inner join (
    select i.*, row_number() over(partition by id_location order by path) rn
    from table_images i
) i on i.id_location_id = l.id
group by l.id
```

You can add more conditional expressions to the `select` clause to handle more images per location.

Note that `row_number()` is available in MySQL 8.0 only.